# To show thumbnails of Images sent on SendBird channel chat

Tags: javascript, react-native, sendbird

I want to show thumbnails of images sent from chat over SendBird React native app code.

thumbnails sizes are already defined but could not show thumbnail graphics of image sent. By default blue color is filled on thumbnail

```
export const sbSendFileMessage = (channel, file, callback) => {
const data = '';
const customType = '';        
const thumbSizeList = [{'maxWidth': 160, 'maxHeight': 160}];
        return channel.sendFileMessage(file,data,customType,thumbSizeList,
        (message, error) => { callback(message, error) });
}
#where do i specify to pass the image graphic to thumbnail ?
```

Comment: [The docs say that this is a premium feature](https://docs.sendbird.com/javascript/open_channel_advanced#3_generate_thumbnails_of_a_file_message). Are you paying for access to those properties?

Comment: @Brian Nope. Thats it?

Comment: That's what I would assume.

Comment: @Brian Thanks !

Comment: In SendBird's docs you can find Brian's point mentioned here. https://docs.sendbird.com/javascript/group_channel_advanced#3_generate_thumbnails_of_a_file_message